# Como imprimir uma lista dinâmica em c++?

Tags: c++, lista, visual-studio

Boa noite! é meu primeiro post aqui então por favor caso informei algo de errado, sintam-se livre para corrigir.
Fiz uma lista dinâmica de char, porém estou com dificuldade de imprimir a lista inteira na tela, ao tentar imprimir, ele imprime somente o primeiro caractere e depois para de compilar afirmando que algum dos outros caracteres apontam para Nullptr. Abaixo colocarei a .h da classe Nodo ,a minha função e o main.

A classe Nodo:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Nodo
{
protected:
    char caractere;
    Nodo* proximo;
    Nodo* anterior;
public:
    Nodo();
    ~Nodo();
    void setcaractere(char c);
    void setProximo(Nodo* p);
    Nodo* getAnterior();
    char getcaractere();
    Nodo* getProximo();
    void setAnterior(Nodo* anter);
};
```

Função imprimir:

```
{
    Nodo* ptr8 = new Nodo;
    Nodo* ptr9 = new Nodo;
    ptr9 = inicio;
    for (int i = 0; i < tamanho; i++) 
    {
        cout << ptr9->getcaractere() << endl;
        ptr8 = inicio->getProximo();
        ptr9 = ptr8;
    }
}
```

Meu main:

```
#include "Nodo.h"
#include"Lista.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    Lista lista;
    lista.push_front('a');
    lista.push_back('b');
    lista.push_back('c');
    lista.push_front('d');
    lista.imprimir();
    lista.pop_back();
    lista.pop_front();
    if (!lista.empty())
    {
        cout << lista.front() << endl;
        cout << lista.back() << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "pilha vazia" << endl;
    }
    lista.remove();
    lista.salvarTXT();
    lista.back();
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Não consegui entender o que tentou fazer ou mesmo perguntar.

No código abaixo parece que você está usando os métodos de lista fornecidos pela linguagem...

```
 {
    Lista lista;
    lista.push_front('a');
    lista.push_back('b');
    lista.push_back('c');
    lista.push_front('d');
    lista.imprimir();
    lista.pop_back();
    lista.pop_front();
    if (!lista.empty())
    {
        cout << lista.front() << endl;
        cout << lista.back() << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "pilha vazia" << endl;
    }
    lista.remove();
    lista.salvarTXT();
    lista.back();
```

Ou você implementou metodos com o mesmo nome para sua classe e não postou?

E onde está o resto do código?

E sobre essa parte

```
class Nodo
{
protected:
    char caractere;
    Nodo* proximo;
    Nodo* anterior;
public:
    Nodo();
    ~Nodo();
    void setcaractere(char c);
    void setProximo(Nodo* p);
    Nodo* getAnterior();
    char getcaractere();
    Nodo* getProximo();
    void setAnterior(Nodo* anter);
};
```

Qual a idéia de implementar isso e ao mesmo tempo as outras funções que mostrou? Parecem ser a mesma coisa...

- Entenda que uma lista é um container. A lista tem nós, e cada nó em geral tem uma referência a um dado.
- uma lista não é um nó.
- um nó não é uma lista.
- um nó não é um dado.

Se pretende usar a lista como oferecida em #include  entenda que elá é uma classe iterável e então você pode usar um iterator para percorrer a lista, ou mesmo um for para mostrar os valores. O comum é criar uma classe para seus dados e colocar a lista dentro. E redefinir o operador << para mostrar a lista.

Se for isso que pretende fazer, usar a lista como fornecida, responda e escrevo um exemplo.

Se quer usar isso em sua implementação de lista basta implementar alguns métodos, como begin() end() e os operadores * != e ++ eu acho.

Comment: Obrigada! sim, tinha criado a função pop, top e push, mas não coloquei pois eram imensas

Comment: Entendo. Mas sem o código compilável fica difícil de ajudar. E essas funções serem imensas é algo a pensar, porque em geral tem poucas linhas, umas 10/15.